How to auto click follow tiktok with accessiblity
this is image in uiautomator viewerCan I ask how to automatically click follow on tiktok with accessibility permission? but the follow tiktok button has clickable as false.
and with button have clickable is true ,i will code
                List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.instagram.android:id/profile_header_follow_button");
                for (AccessibilityNodeInfo n : list) {
                    if (n.getText() != null && n.getText().toString().equals("Theo dõi")) {
                        n.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);

